# Is it possible to fool app on Jailbroken iPhone and make fake inapp purchases

Tags: iphone, security, app-store, in-app

We're launching an app that is selling the service through inapp purchases.
Currently we asessing a risk of Jailbroken devices.

Is it possible that a user with a jailbroken iphone simulates an inapp purchase without paying for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it is possible that some app can simulates an inapp purchase without paying for it.

To prevent this, you should check the IAP transaction and receipt from app store.
You can reference [Verifying Store Receipts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1) from the Apple In-App Purchase Programming Guide.

Comment: Thanks Hanon, is it possible to control this programatically?

Comment: Yes you can, i updated my answer. You can go to the link and see it. FYI, I test my app (with IAP) before with a jb device and the cracker app. Then I log both non-jb and jb device transaction to see the differences. And find that you can do something in your code to prevent the crack.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible and there are system tweaks for jailbroken ios devices that do exactly what you're talking about, take a look here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3cmwwjISAo

this is of course pretty illegal i believe.

Comment: Thanks for the video:( It is too bad that it is possible, however I guess there should be some option from apple to control the real transaction.. Any ideas?

Comment: Look over here, might have an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465713/how-to-prevent-iap-cracker