# Is there a way to access another program's data on the run? Xcode/iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was thinking of doing some kind of extension for whatsapp, but I believe Xcode limits my access to other apps. Maybe even iOS itself. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Xcode. All 3rd party iOS apps run in their own sandbox. The only way one app can access the data of another is if both apps agree ahead of time to do so using either the pasteboard, the keychain, or by launching the other app and passing data on the URL.

No 3rd party app can access the files of another app. This is a deliberate (and good) design of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can check of app existing, how in

[How to detect “IAP crackers”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465713/how-to-detect-iap-crackers)

by

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Applications/Cydia.app"]
```

Try look at this way, maybe you can find anything.